# Multiple addpath commands result in slow second call

Tags: matlab

I've had a startup script which sets my default settings as well as defines my working directory and adds all relevant paths. In this script, there is the command

```
addpath(genpath(pwd))
```

which simply adds all of the subfolders within my current directory.

Recently I got a new SSD and tried to move most of my non-program files over to it. Both drives work fine and are able to communicate smoothly. However, now I notice that if I try to call the command twice, the first command executes in less than a second whereas the second command continues to execute (20+ minutes and still running).

I am fairly certain I did not have this problem before and it occurs if a single file in the addpath is already on MATLABPATH. Furthermore, adding the files to the permanent MATLABPATH and restarting MATLAB also results in a soft error (runs forever without any actual error). This error persists for paths on both drives but the only change is that I got a new drive.

Edit: It appears to be getting stuck on line 94 of "addpath"

```
path(p, mp);
```

I am using Windows 10 on MATLAB 2017b.

Thank you for your help

Comment: None, it just runs forever on an operation that otherwise takes less than a second.

Comment: if you `ctrl-c` during this 20+minutes, does it stop? https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/stop-execution.html

Comment: No, it's in the middle of some large block execution so it will continue to run until it finishes that particular line. Edited comment to include line it gets stuck on